# Error in installation of yara 3.3.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

I am trying to install `yara3.3.0` and I got the following error:

> ./bootstrap.sh: autoreconf: not found.

This error occurred during the installation of `yara3.3.0`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

or this

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

or this

```
sudo apt-get install dh-autoreconf
```